# Is there a word in English which refers to art that describes a place?

Tags: single-word-requests

To try and make things a bit clearer, there is the word 'ekphrasis', which refers to a work of art which describes another work of art. Such as 'the ekphrastic poem' (a poem which describes another work of art).

What I am wondering is if there is a dedicated word for art or literature which describes as a place or location, such as William Blake's poem 'London', which describes the location of London. Is there a word which would essentially mean 'Blake's [word which describes art that describes a place] poem...'.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: If such a word existed it might be "topophrasic"

Comment: @J.Taylor One meaning of "topology" is the "scientific study of a locality"(OED). This is not to be confused with the branch of mathematics, known as "topology". Yes, I see what you mean about "topophrasic".

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `Verisimilitude`? Which means "the appearance of being true or real".

Answer (score 1):

The closest term I can find that has wide usage is "ode". Though an ode isn't necessarily about a place, it certainly can be. And of course, an ode is definitively for written works, but one could apply it with artistic license to other media.

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* defines "ode" as (emphasis mine):

> a lyric poem in the form of an address **to a particular subject**, often elevated in style or manner and written in varied or irregular meter.

Other more applicable phrases found in Google, but not universally recognized include "place art" and "setting art".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, ode is definitely a good  word which I didn't think of. But, I discovered that there actually is a word! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographical_poetry

Comment: Interesting find, congrats. May I ask you consider upvoting my answer as thanks?